# Cocoapods headers not found when building application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, cocoapods

For the past few days I've been attempting to build an application, which keeps failing and gives the message *"file not found"*. My friend is able to build the application on his computer, but I've tried on 3 computers and all 3 have been giving me the same error. I've tried uninstalling & reinstalling the cocoapods gem, deleting the pods and podfile.lock and reinstalling & upgrading pods without any luck. When I go into the pods folder, I see all the files, and it even autocompletes the file name in the `prefix.pch` file (Where the issue occurs). I'm using the same cocoapods as my friend (v0.34.4) & Xcode v6.1.

Also worth noting - the `XCTest.framework`, `Tests.xctest` and the `libpods` (but not the expanded pods folders) are all red.

Here's the error I get when compiling:

```
ProcessPCH /Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dojnoizofbzbmmeascbukgzbsthh/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/app-Prefix-ahotoqoympyvtcaartebeekroqoj/app-Prefix.pch.pch app/app-Prefix.pch normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/name/app
export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -iquote /Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dojnoizofbzbmmeascbukgzbsthh/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appTests.build/appTests-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dojnoizofbzbmmeascbukgzbsthh/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appTests.build/appTests-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dojnoizofbzbmmeascbukgzbsthh/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appTests.build/appTests-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dojnoizofbzbmmeascbukgzbsthh/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appTests.build/appTests-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dojnoizofbzbmmeascbukgzbsthh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dojnoizofbzbmmeascbukgzbsthh/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appTests.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dojnoizofbzbmmeascbukgzbsthh/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appTests.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dojnoizofbzbmmeascbukgzbsthh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -MD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dojnoizofbzbmmeascbukgzbsthh/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/app-Prefix-ahotoqoympyvtcaartebeekroqoj/app-Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/name/app/app/app-Prefix.pch -o /Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dojnoizofbzbmmeascbukgzbsthh/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/app-Prefix-ahotoqoympyvtcaartebeekroqoj/app-Prefix.pch.pch --serialize-diagnostics /Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dojnoizofbzbmmeascbukgzbsthh/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/app-Prefix-ahotoqoympyvtcaartebeekroqoj/app-Prefix.pch.dia 
/Users/name/app/app/app-Prefix.pch:17:13: fatal error: 'Parse/Parse.h' file not found
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
        ^1 error generated.
```

Comment: Crazy question: are you launching the .xcworkspace file?

Comment: Yep I've been using it the whole time.

Comment: Darn. And have you done a clean? What about a `pod update` ?

Comment: Yeah I did both those things :(

Comment: If the project is in source control, can you try deleting the folder it's in, removing the local repo, and redownloading it from the source?

Comment: Yeah, I have it on github. I tried doing that.

Comment: What about trying the Xcode 6.1.1 GM seed?

Comment: No dice. I had previously tried reinstalling Xcode as well.

Comment: What's the contents of your podfile?

Comment: source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'Parse', '~> 1.4'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtils', '~> 1.4'
pod 'ParseUI', '~> 1.0'
pod 'JVFloatLabeledTextField', '~> 0.0'
pod 'MRProgress', '0.8'
pod 'IOSLinkedInAPI', '~> 2.0'
pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', '~> 1.2'
pod 'Firebase', '~> 2.0'
pod 'YLMoment', '~> 0.5'
pod 'RPFloatingPlaceholders', '~> 0.2'
pod 'HockeySDK', '~> 3.6'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'
pod 'ios-image-editor', '~> 1.1'
pod 'CardIO', '~> 3.10'
pod 'Stripe', '~> 2.2'

Comment: Are you building for iOS 8? Could you try switching it to :ios, '8.0'?

Comment: @remus just tried that. Unfortunately, still showing same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get the app to build.

Here's what I did:
I went to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Schemes
I subsequently unchecked the box under the Target -> Tests for "Analyze".

[image: screenshot]

As the build had been previously failing at that point, so by unchecking it I was able to run it with no issues. Having spent time using it over the last few hours, I find it to be working normally, and can vouch that the issues mentioned previously by xCode have had no impact on real world usage (product is on market with many users).

Thanks for the folks that previously helped out.